# How to Bend/curve edges

Tags: edges

I'm trying to make a detail for a glass that i made and i wanna make the Edges bend like the picture bellow
[image]

as you can see there are bendy details on a glass, and i'm confused how to make that.

Comment: I've added an answer because I thought you were looking to bevel edges. But re-reading your question it seems you meant the fact that the edges of the glass slightly curve downwards to the center line in the photograph? They are not really curved, the glass has a circular cross section, so the perspective makes it look curved from certain angles...

Comment: yes, but how do i make the curve like that cus i wanna make it looks similar to the picture. Thanks for your answer btw

Comment: As I said, it's not a curved edge, it's a matter of perspective. You have to set up the camera so that it looks similar. At the moment you're in orthographic front view. Hit 5 on the numpad to switch to perspective view in the 3D Editor window. Or hit 0 on the numpad to switch to camera view.

Comment: thanks! you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the *Bevel Tool*. Select the edges you want to bevel in *Edit Mode*, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, drag the mouse to start beveling the edges, use the scroll wheel to set the number of segments.

For a more detailed description of the *Bevel Tool* read this article in the Blender Manual:

[Bevel Edges](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/bevel.html)

There's also a non-destructive way to bevel the edges:

[Bevel Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/bevel.html)